# error: 'ValueError: _names_ are reserved for future Enum use'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, linux, command-line-interface

I'm deploying my Django project on a Linux server. When I run the command `python manage.py collectstatic`I get the following error:

```
  File "/home/student/PickFeel/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/enums.py", line 81, in TextChoices
    def _generate_next_value_(name, start, count, last_values):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/enum.py", line 61, in __setitem__
    raise ValueError('_names_ are reserved for future Enum use')
ValueError: _names_ are reserved for future Enum use
```

enum.py is a system generated file.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Upgrade to python3. 8 and it should work.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60579937/enum-valueerror-python3-when-starting-django/61533214#61533214

Comment: Thank you that worked. Instead of using 'python manage.py collectstatic' I used ''python3.8 manage.py collectstatic'. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens since `python3.5` does not support `_missing_` function for enums. It is supported in `python3.8` [see here from the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#finer-points)

Consider upgrading your python version to `3.8` or any other version that supports the `_missing_` function.

If you already have a latest version then use the suitable command, e.g. instead of this

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Do

```
python3.x manage.py collectstatic
```